# How to change data after success URLs sent to partner API's if they can only be GET requests?

Tags: http, get, stripe-payments, api-design, idempotent

A lot of times there's a parameter in a partner API endpoint like `success_url` where you provide the partner API with an endpoint on your internal API to redirect the client.

For example, on Stripe you can create a [checkout session](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object) using `POST /v1/checkout/sessions`. In the body you send Stripe a [`success_url`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-success_url). You redirect the client to Stripe where they make their payment. After they complete their payment successfully, Stripe will redirect the client to that `success_url` you included.

Since you are only sending a URL aren't all of these requests only GET requests? And if so, a GET is defined in the HTTP protocol as idempotent and safe. So I couldn't use this request to make [changes to data](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/188860/why-shouldnt-a-get-request-change-data-on-the-server) on my server. But after a successful purchase, I will want to make changes like updating or creating an `Order` on my server, updating stock left for the `Item`, etc.

How can I make changes after these success, refresh, return, or cancel URL's if they are all GET requests?

Comment: Greetings Dash ... you can make changes as you see fit by responding to the name-value pairs in the GET request. Even though the operational semantics of GET vs POST are different, *technically* the only difference is whether the name value pairs came in through the BODY parameter, or as part of the URL.

Comment: Thanks, I thought there was more to the differences between POST and GET requests. I thought it was bad practice to make changes in GET requests because certain things with how the browser caches or refreshes these requests differently. Something like (this is going to be poorly worded and probably partially incorrect) the browser will make multiple requests if the request fails or the page refreshes on a GET request, but not on a POST request because it knows the post requests can create new objects, so multiple requests would create duplicate objects.

Comment: Generally, what you are saying is reasonable, but only so long as the designers of the API follow the operational semantics of HTTP. That is not always the case. Routinely, E-commerce platforms will deviate from these semantics for convenience sake. For example, some vendors use GET instead of POST because it is easier to send directly from a browser address bar. I often use https://requestbin.net/ to catch and evaluate GET vs POST callbacks.